# Angularjs splice in loop

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am building this angularjs app, its my first one. So huge learning curve. I cant seem to to delete items as well as my search doesn't work. I managed to get column sorting and pagination to work though.

I get no errors so i am not sure why the search and deleting of item row in table isnt working.

I have tried using this:

```
       $scope.remove = function(client){
            for(var i = $scope.clients.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
                if($scope.clients[i].name == client.name){
                        $scope.clients.splice(i,1);
                }
            }
        }
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/f2ozbP4JxrRSvRGJAmQi

ANSWER, WORKING:

Thanks @DTing

```
  $scope.remove = function(client){
      $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filteredItems.filter(function(item) {
        return item.name !== client.name;
      });
      $scope.groupToPages();
    }
```

Comment: can you create [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/) with sample?

Comment: I am going to try, give me a few minutes thanks

Comment: I think you should have a remove function in your score, right ?

Comment: @Fourat remove function in my score?

Comment: Added a working example to bottom of my question. So both my search and remove is not working

Comment: @dreamsynk yes ! You called the ng-click directive `data-ng-click="remove($index)"`then you need to have a remove function in your $scope that takes an index argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be your remove function:

```
        $scope.remove = function(client){
            for(var i = $scope.pagedItems[$scope.currentPage].length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
                if($scope.pagedItems[$scope.currentPage][i].name == client.name){
                    $scope.pagedItems[$scope.currentPage].splice(i,1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

This should be your search function (note creation of $scope.clientsCopy):

```
        $scope.clientsCopy = angular.copy(data);

        $scope.searchMatch = function (haystack, needle) {
            if (!needle) {
                return true;
            }
            return haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        };

        // init the filtered items
        $scope.search = function () {
            $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.clientsCopy, function (item) {
                for(var attr in item) {
                    if ($scope.searchMatch(item.name, $scope.query))
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            );
            // take care of the sorting order
            if ($scope.sortField !== '') {
                $scope.filteredItems = $filter('orderBy')($scope.filteredItems, $scope.sortField, $scope.reverse);
            }
            $scope.currentPage = 0;
            // now group by pages
            $scope.groupToPages();
        };
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eIrhcuo66DLoSdKYbWYs?p=preview)

Comment: But its not working with the pagination, page two wont let me remove items?

Comment: Thanks m8, that works as well. Do you have any idea why my search isnt working?

Comment: @dreamsynk See update for search. The Plunker is updated to test.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to alter your `$scope.clients` which actually is empty because in your `groupToPages` function you set it to an empty array and repopulate or use it.

```
$scope.groupToPages = function () {
        $scope.clients = [];
```

You can get it to work by removing items from your filteredItems array.

```
$scope.remove = function(client){
  $scope.filteredItems.splice($scope.filteredItems.indexOf(client),1);
  $scope.groupToPages();
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/z9NxW2FgYDlgLB20daO9?p=preview

Comment: Hi, your solution also works but just not on with the pagination, doesnt work on page two

Comment: It's working in the plunker. Sorry i posted the wrong link earlier.

Comment: Hi, thanks that is working, must of not refreshed correctly. Thanks alot m8, any idea why my search isnt working? I usually try figure this stuff out myself, I am only on stackoverflow after 4 hours of headaches.

Comment: I would not empty an array that way in angular. If ever there is another scope watching this, it wont be updated as far as you set $scope.clients to another reference

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe, I am not sure what you mean. I am new to angular, and my JS is very average, so I am still trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: @dreamsynk My code example replaces the $scope.filteredItems with another array, which will cause problems if it is watched. I'll update the example. The search has the same problem as the remove. You are filtering an empty array because you cleared it out when you grouped the pages.

Comment: @DTing to empty an array without losing its reference, the simplest way I use is ``$scope.clients.length = 0``

Comment: @dreamsynk : $watch is watching the reference of your object. If you assign your object to a new reference, angular wont see it, because your old reference is still there. You don't alter your array, you replace it by another.